# MonoTouch Working with Views and Controllers

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a screen in my MonoTouch C# app that lets users search for restaurants. The user can search for restaurants nearby, anywhere, or recently visited. These three options are presented as a segmented control. When a user clicks an item in the segmented control, I toggle the visible views. In other words each option represents its own view.

I want each view to have its own table view controller such that when a user clicks a restaurant, more details are given to the user. From what I can tell, I need to implement the approach shown here: http://www.alexyork.net/blog/post/UINavigationController-with-MonoTouch-Building-a-simple-RSS-reader-Part-1.aspx

My problem is, I can't seem to figure out a way to add a controller to a view. In my scenario, I believe I need to add a UITableViewController to each UIView (one for each segmented control item). Is this possible? If so, how? If it is not possible, how should I go about accomplishing my goal? This seems simple enough, but I seem to be way off and am misunderstanding something. Here is the method I'm calling when the ViewDidLoad event is hit:

```
private void LoadViews()
{
  int subViewHeight = 320;

  #region Nearby View

  RectangleF nearbyRectangle = new RectangleF(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, subViewHeight);
  this.nearbyView = new UIView(nearbyRectangle);
  this.nearbyView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;

  this.nearbyTableViewController = new NearbyTableViewController(IntPtr.Zero);  
  this.NavigationController.PushViewController(nearbyTableViewController, false);
  this.View.Add(nearbyView);

  #endregion Nearby View

  #region Elsewhere View

  RectangleF elsewhereRectangle = new RectangleF(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, subViewHeight);
  this.elsewhereView = new UIView(elsewhereRectangle);
  this.elsewhereView.Hidden = true;
  this.elsewhereView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;

  // Add the search text field
  UITextField searchElsewhereTextField = new UITextField();
  searchElsewhereTextField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
  searchElsewhereTextField.Frame = new RectangleF(20, 13, 200, 31);
  searchElsewhereTextField.Placeholder = "query";
  this.elsewhereView.AddSubview(searchElsewhereTextField);

  // Add the search button
  UIButton searchButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
  searchButton.Frame = new RectangleF((UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 90), 13, 70, 31);
  searchButton.SetTitle("Search", UIControlState.Normal);
  this.elsewhereView.AddSubview(searchButton);

  // Add the results table
  this.elsewhereTableView = new UITableView(new RectangleF(0, 52, 
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, subViewHeight-70), UITableViewStyle.Plain);
  this.elsewhereTableView.Source = new NearbyListDataSource(this);          
  this.elsewhereView.AddSubview(elsewhereTableView);

  this.View.Add(elsewhereView);

  #endregion Elsewhere View

  #region Recent View

  RectangleF recentRectangle = new RectangleF(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, subViewHeight);
  this.recentView = new UIView(recentRectangle);
  this.recentView.Hidden = true;

  this.recentTableView = new UITableView(new RectangleF(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, subViewHeight), UITableViewStyle.Plain);
  this.recentTableView.Source = new NearbyListDataSource(this);         
  this.recentView.AddSubview(recentTableView);

  this.View.Add(recentView);

  #endregion Recent View
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you want to transition between UIViewControllers you would use UINavigationController and "push" them into the screen. In this case you want a UISegmentedControl inside the UINavigationController's UINavigationBar.

```
this.PushViewController(myRecentRestaurantsViewController, true);
```

When the associated item is clicked in the segmented control, you call the method above to push the appropriate controller into view.

Basically UIViewControllers are "containers" for views. If you ever want to add a ViewController's View to another ViewController's view please look at my blog post on custom containers:

http://blog.devnos.com/wont-somebody-please-think-of-the-children

Comment: Hello, I just added my code to the question. Thank you for your response. I'm still having issues. Would you please consider reviewing my code and telling me what I'm doing wrong? I'm completely frustrated by this. Thank you!

Comment: In more complex cases where you cannot reduce the desired behavior to a few lines of code, please create a small self-contained sample application for review.